# Python find max in list of lists and elements with undefined number of integers and floats

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, nested-lists

I have a big list of list. I am trying to find max and min in it. Previous questions on this consists lists with strings and this question is differen.t

```
    big_list = [[137.83,81.80,198.56],0.0,[200.37,151.55,165.26, 211.84],
 0.0,[1,2,3],4,[5,6,0,5,7,8],0,[2,1,4,5],[9,1,-2]]
```

My code:

```
max =  max(list(map(max,boxs_list)))
```

Present output:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Are you expecting to find max = 9 and min =-1 from the list you provided ?

Comment: Also, you say you have a big list of lists but your example is a "big" list of lists and integers

Comment: Yes. Max=9 and min = -2

Comment: @tomgalpin I provided here a sample list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flatten an irregular list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you need the list to contain only lists

```
np.max(np.concatenate([l if isinstance(l,list) else [l] for l in big_list]))
```

or

```
max(map(max,[l if isinstance(l,list) else [l] for l in big_list]))
```

**Output**

```
9
```

**EDIT: get len of sublist**

```
lens = [len(l) if isinstance(l,list) else 1 for l in big_list]
#[3, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 6, 1, 4, 3]
```

if you only want consider list:

```
#lens = [len(l) if isinstance(l,list) else None for l in big_list]
#[3, None, 4, None, 3, None, 6, None, 4, 3]
```

We could do as when we got the max:

```
list(map(len,[l if isinstance(l,list) else [l] for l in big_list]))
#[3, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 6, 1, 4, 3]
```

**I think the best way is:**

```
list(map(lambda x: len(x) if isinstance(x,list) else None ,big_list))
#[3, None, 4, None, 3, None, 6, None, 4, 3]
```

Comment: I liked your online code: `np.max(np.concatenate([l if isinstance(l,list) else [l] for l in big_list]))`. This works fine. Do above `concatenate` work better?

Comment: It depends on the specific case but I think that the best map works here

Comment: My `big_list' also has elements. Does your code considers only lists of list? or it considers all values inside that list?

Comment: `max(map(max,[l if isinstance(l,list) else [l] for l in big_list]))` you don't need `list` here:)

Comment: it consider all values

Comment: In above question, how to find length of each sublist?

Comment: If there is no list but there is a value, is the length 1?

Comment: I submitted a new question on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59990774/python-find-size-of-each-sublist-in-a-list/59990915#59990915

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following, using `max()` and `min()` with generator expressions, and a check with `isinstance()` to see if each element is a list or not.

```
>>> min(sl if not isinstance(sl, list) else min(sl) for sl in big_list)
-2
>>> max(sl if not isinstance(sl, list) else max(sl) for sl in big_list)
9
```