# Python find size of each sublist in a list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a big list of floats and integers as given below. I want to find the length of each sublist by neglecting empty or single elements.

```
big_list = [[137.83,81.80,198.56],0.0,[200.37,151.55,165.26, 211.84],
 0.0,[1,2,3],4,[5,6,0,5,7,8],0,[2,1,4,5],[9,1,-2]]
```

My present code:

```
list_len = []
for i in big_list: 
     list_len.append(len(i))
```

Present output:

```
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()
```

Expected output:

```
list_len = [3,4,3,6,4,3] # list_len should neglect elements like 0, 4 in big_list.
```

Comment: either check type or catch exceptions

Comment: "# list_len should neglect elements like 0, 4 in big_list" sounds like some logic that you need to build into your script

Comment: What's the use of pandas here?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I want to consider only lists, not elements. I want to neglect them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res = [len(l) for l in big_list if isinstance(l, list) and len(l)> 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go for:

```
big_list = [(137.83,81.80,198.56),0.0,np.array([200.37,151.55,165.26, 211.84]),
 0.0,[1,2,3],4,[5,6,0,5,7,8],0,[2,1,4,5],[9,1,-2]]

list_len = [len(x) for x in big_list if hasattr(x, '__len__') and len(x)>0]
```

which works with numpy arrays and tuple as well

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension with list type checking like this:

```py
big_list = [[137.83,81.80,198.56],0.0,[200.37,151.55,165.26, 211.84],
 0.0,[1,2,3],4,[5,6,0,5,7,8],0,[2,1,4,5],[9,1,-2]]

lengths = [
    len(sub_list) for sub_list in big_list if isinstance(sub_list, list)
]
print(lengths)

>>> [3, 4, 3, 6, 4, 3]
```

Comment: It's possible that those are NumPy arrays... Instead of `isinstance(sub_list, list)` you could also check for something like `hasattr(sub_list, '__len__')`.

Comment: @jdehesa that's smart, you should add it in another answer!

Answer (score 1):

```py
list(map(len, filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, list), big_list)))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use compressed list with if-else statements:

```
list_len = [len(x) for x in big_list if isinstance(x,list)]
```

Comment: doesn't answer the question for 0 len lists.